# Chartjs include external options

Tags: charts

I've just started using chart.js

I have different bar and line charts across different pages.

All the graphs have certain options that are the same like grid line a tooltip styling.

Is it possible to store these settings externally and apply them to each page.

Comment: can you describe more detail for me, i think i can help you =)

Comment: Trying to think what more i can say. I have a site with multiple pages, each page has a graph or bar chart. Each has different data and colors so I set this in each graph separately. They have common options like the styling of the tooltip. Instead of typing this in each graph, can I include or add these options from a external file

Answer (score 0):

Global Settings
Chart.js uses a set of global settings that determine how every chart will be rendered. If you wish to change any of settings from the library defaults you should include the global settings section below in your script:

```
// Set the global Chart values (these will apply to all charts)
Chart.defaults.global = {
  // Boolean - Whether to animate the chart
  animation: true,

  // Number - Number of animation steps
  animationSteps: 60,

  // String - Animation easing effect
  // Possible effects are:
  // [easeInOutQuart, linear, easeOutBounce, easeInBack, easeInOutQuad,
  //  easeOutQuart, easeOutQuad, easeInOutBounce, easeOutSine, easeInOutCubic,
  //  easeInExpo, easeInOutBack, easeInCirc, easeInOutElastic, easeOutBack,
  //  easeInQuad, easeInOutExpo, easeInQuart, easeOutQuint, easeInOutCirc,
  //  easeInSine, easeOutExpo, easeOutCirc, easeOutCubic, easeInQuint,
  //  easeInElastic, easeInOutSine, easeInOutQuint, easeInBounce,
  //  easeOutElastic, easeInCubic]
  animationEasing: "easeOutQuart",

  // Boolean - If we should show the scale at all
  showScale: true,

  // Boolean - If we want to override with a hard coded scale
  scaleOverride: false,

  // ** Required if scaleOverride is true **
  // Number - The number of steps in a hard coded scale
  scaleSteps: null,
  // Number - The value jump in the hard coded scale
  scaleStepWidth: null,
  // Number - The scale starting value
  scaleStartValue: null,

  // String - Colour of the scale line
  scaleLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.1)",

  // Number - Pixel width of the scale line
  scaleLineWidth: 1,

  // Boolean - Whether to show labels on the scale
  scaleShowLabels: true,

  // Interpolated JS string - can access value
  scaleLabel: "<%=value%>",

  // Boolean - Whether the scale should stick to integers, not floats even if drawing space is there
  scaleIntegersOnly: true,

  // Boolean - Whether the scale should start at zero, or an order of magnitude down from the lowest value
  scaleBeginAtZero: false,

  // String - Scale label font declaration for the scale label
  scaleFontFamily: "'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif",

  // Number - Scale label font size in pixels
  scaleFontSize: 12,

  // String - Scale label font weight style
  scaleFontStyle: "normal",

  // String - Scale label font colour
  scaleFontColor: "#666",

  // Boolean - whether or not the chart should be responsive and resize when the browser does.
  responsive: false,

  // Boolean - whether to maintain the starting aspect ratio or not when responsive, if set to false, will take up entire container
  maintainAspectRatio: true,

  // Boolean - Determines whether to draw tooltips on the canvas or not
  showTooltips: true,

  // Function - Determines whether to execute the customTooltips function instead of drawing the built in tooltips (See [Advanced - External Tooltips](#advanced-usage-external-tooltips))
  customTooltips: false,

  // Array - Array of string names to attach tooltip events
  tooltipEvents: ["mousemove", "touchstart", "touchmove"],

  // String - Tooltip background colour
  tooltipFillColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)",

  // String - Tooltip label font declaration for the scale label
  tooltipFontFamily: "'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif",

  // Number - Tooltip label font size in pixels
  tooltipFontSize: 14,

  // String - Tooltip font weight style
  tooltipFontStyle: "normal",

  // String - Tooltip label font colour
  tooltipFontColor: "#fff",

  // String - Tooltip title font declaration for the scale label
  tooltipTitleFontFamily: "'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif",

  // Number - Tooltip title font size in pixels
  tooltipTitleFontSize: 14,

  // String - Tooltip title font weight style
  tooltipTitleFontStyle: "bold",

  // String - Tooltip title font colour
  tooltipTitleFontColor: "#fff",

  // String - Tooltip title template
  tooltipTitleTemplate: "<%= label%>",

  // Number - pixel width of padding around tooltip text
  tooltipYPadding: 6,

  // Number - pixel width of padding around tooltip text
  tooltipXPadding: 6,

  // Number - Size of the caret on the tooltip
  tooltipCaretSize: 8,

  // Number - Pixel radius of the tooltip border
  tooltipCornerRadius: 6,

  // Number - Pixel offset from point x to tooltip edge
  tooltipXOffset: 10,

  // String - Template string for single tooltips
  tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value %>",

  // String - Template string for multiple tooltips
  multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= value %>",

  // Function - Will fire on animation progression.
  onAnimationProgress: function(){},

  // Function - Will fire on animation completion.
  onAnimationComplete: function(){}
}
```

I'm copy from http://microbuilder.io/blog/2016/01/10/plotting-json-data-with-chart-js.html. i think this can help you friend.

P/s: sorry because my english is not good =)